# How to speed up the below code to compute LBP on CPU significantly?

Tags: c, optimization, x86, sse, simd

The below code is called intensively in the object detection program and costs about 80% execution time. Is there any way to speed it up significantly?

```
#define CALC_SUM_(p0, p1, p2, p3, offset) ((p0)[offset] - (p1)[offset] - (p2)[offset] + (p3)[offset])
inline int calc_lbp2(float *p[], int offset)
{
    int cval = CALC_SUM_( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset );

    return (CALC_SUM_( p[0],  p[1],  p[4],  p[5],  offset ) >= cval ? 128 : 0) |   // 0
           (CALC_SUM_( p[1],  p[2],  p[5],  p[6],  offset ) >= cval ? 64 : 0) |    // 1
           (CALC_SUM_( p[2],  p[3],  p[6],  p[7],  offset ) >= cval ? 32 : 0) |    // 2
           (CALC_SUM_( p[6],  p[7],  p[10], p[11], offset ) >= cval ? 16 : 0) |  // 5
           (CALC_SUM_( p[10], p[11], p[14], p[15], offset ) >= cval ? 8 : 0)|  // 8
           (CALC_SUM_( p[9],  p[10], p[13], p[14], offset ) >= cval ? 4 : 0)|   // 7
           (CALC_SUM_( p[8],  p[9],  p[12], p[13], offset ) >= cval ? 2 : 0)|    // 6
           (CALC_SUM_( p[4],  p[5],  p[8],  p[9],  offset ) >= cval ? 1 : 0);
}
```

I tried SSE, but the program cost more 50ms about (the original execution time is about 170 ms):

```
inline int calc_lbp_sse(float *p[], int offset)
{
    static unsigned short bits[] = {0x0080, 0x0040, 0x0020, 0x0010, 0x0008, 0x0004, 0x0002, 0x0001};
    short c = CALC_SUM_( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset );
    __m128i a = _mm_setr_epi16
                (
                    CALC_SUM_( p[0],  p[1],  p[4],  p[5],  offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[1],  p[2],  p[5],  p[6],  offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[2],  p[3],  p[6],  p[7],  offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[6],  p[7],  p[10], p[11], offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[10], p[11], p[14], p[15], offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[9],  p[10], p[13], p[14], offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[8],  p[9],  p[12], p[13], offset ),
                    CALC_SUM_( p[4],  p[5],  p[8],  p[9],  offset )
                );
    __m128i b = _mm_setr_epi16(c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c);

    __m128i res = _mm_cmplt_epi16(b,a);
    unsigned short* vals = (unsigned short*)&res;

    return ((vals[0]&bits[0]) | (vals[1]&bits[1]) | (vals[2]&bits[2]) | (vals[3]&bits[3]) |
            (vals[4]&bits[4]) | (vals[5]&bits[5]) |(vals[6]&bits[6]) |(vals[7]&bits[7]));
}
```

Comment: Right now you're using SSE to speed up the evaluation of the LBP at a single location. Consider refactoring the code s.t. you're evaluating the LBP for 8 or 16 consecutive pixels in a row; This may work out much better.

Comment: Also be aware that LBP evaluation has an intrinsically ugly memory access pattern, and you are likely to get many, many cache misses, especially if your features and image are large.

Comment: did you try replacing all the `... >= cval ? 64 : 0` style expressions with something like `(... >= cval) << 6` to get rid of branches?

Comment: The `set` operations are all complicated composite operations, except `_mm_setzero_si128`. As a general rule, the only OK place to use them is outside a loop. Right now the only thing that's "actually an SSE instruction" is `_mm_cmplt_epi16`, which is nice, but you've already spent more instructions just constructing its operands than you can possibly save at this point. By the way, forming that bitmask smells like `pmovmskb`.

Comment: Can you add the code with your main loop over the pixels? What's especially interesting is how you fill `p` each iteration.

Comment: @Zboson Can't tell you OP's code, but I'm putting my bets on this code having been at least inspired by OpenCV: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.hpp#L463 . I know this because I myself looked at and optimized this particular implementation of LBP on a massively-SIMD machine.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, that does look like the OP's function. Thanks! I did not know about LBP until this question. It looks like something that's difficult to implement efficiently with SIMD. That's why it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your function 200000000 times on my desktop computer and it took 5.3 seconds.  Then I changed this line:

```
int cval = CALC_SUM_( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset );
```

to this:

```
float cval = CALC_SUM_( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset );
```

I reran the same test and it now took 3.0 seconds.  Now I'm not familiar with LBP but it seems like you didn't intentionally mean to cast your center value to an int.  From what I read about LBP, you are just comparing the neighboring values to the center value.  But if casting to int is actually important, then just ignore this answer.

As an aside, I tried what japreiss suggested with replacing the `? :` with `<< 6`, but I got the exact same speeds either way.  So apparently the compiler already optimized that away (I'm using `gcc -O3`).

Comment: I have actually implemented LBP myself (and know that OP's code is sourced from deep in OpenCV) and can affirm that what you found is plausible; If any kind of type conversion is necessary, the performance goes to the dogs. I got a bigger gain out of completely rewriting the LBP evaluation, but that was for a very specialized processor and this margin is too small to explain how I did it.